# OPERA. Dates of figure 15

Tags: experimental-physics, data

What are the real dates that are represented in figure 15, page 24, in the [OpERA paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4897)?

In my opinion, the X axis labels are inconclusive, or absent.

(In the investigation of a crime it is relevant the place and the time of the event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X axis there is not time, it's just six bins.

Each pair of bins is labeled by year, and can be assumed to represent *all* the data taken during that calendar year (or to-date in the case of 2011).

That's going to be multiple periods of "running" each year, with varying beam intensities and both regularly scheduled and unexpected beam stops during the running periods.

You can probably find the beam logs for the SPS with enough digging around CERN's websites (and possibly emailing).

Comment: Well, it is time in units of years :). The plot could have been three dimensional, and would have been if there were more extractions.